# how to retrieve multiple images from database in html <img> tag

Tags: php

I want to retrieve these images from database.

[image: I want to retrieve these images from database.]

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$pass="";
$db="db";
$conn=new mysqli($servername,$username,$pass,$db);

$result=$conn->query("select * from image");


    while($row_brand=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $brand_image=$row_brand['image'];


    ?>
<div class="div1">
<?php
 echo "<img src='uploads/$brand_image' />";
 echo <img src="image.php?id=<? echo $image['id'];?>" /> 
    }
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using this code to fetch all images.
But I want to fetch images in image `<img>` tag.
So please help me that how I fetch all these images in html file with the `<img>` tag.

Comment: `$image['id']` where did this come frome?

Comment: $row_brand['id']; insted of $image['id'];

Comment: 1. You are overwriting your `$brand_image` variable in the loop, 2. You are not using a loop when you display the images, 3. You are trying to access non-existing variables when you try to display the ID.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$pass="";
$db="db";
$conn=new mysqli($servername,$username,$pass,$db);

$result=$conn->query("select * from image");


    while($row_brand=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $brand_image[] = $row_brand;
    }

    ?>

 <?php foreach($brand_image as $brand){ ?>
 <div class="div1">
 <img src='uploads/<?php echo $brand["image"]; ?>' />
 <img src="image.php?id=<? echo $brand['image_id']; ?>" /> 
</div>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Please check this updated code.

Comment: please check front end in image

Comment: i want these six images from image database